# Сортировка многомерного массива

Tags: массивы, php

Ребята, помогите отсортировать массив вида по дате (date)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => 1
            [title] => 1
            [date] => 31 8 2011
            [key] => 1
            [deckr] => 1
            [text] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => 2
            [title] => 2
            [date] => 31 8 2011
            [key] => 2
            [deckr] => 2
            [text] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => 3
            [title] => 3
            [date] => 31 8 2011
            [key] => 3
            [deckr] => 3
            [text] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
usort()
```

2)

```
//Создаем вспомогательный массив
$subArray = array();
//Вычленяем интересующие ключи
foreach($yourArray as $key=>$value){
 $subArray[$key] = $value['date'];
}
//Сортируем подмассив с сохранением ключей
asort($subArray);
//Перезаписываем вместо подзначений значения
foreach($subArray as $key=>$value){
 $subArray['key'] = $yourArray['key'];
}
```

Comment: Аррр, на три секунды обогнали! =)

Comment: Ну, что поделать. =) Зато у вас более подробно описан усорт

Answer (score 1):

Да пребудет с тобой [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)!

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['date'] == $b['date']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['date'] < $b['date']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($ar, "cmp");
```

Да, алгоритм функции cmp хорошо бы поправить. Или даты развернуть в числа.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: вот мой массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => 1
            [title] => 1
            [date] => 30-05-2011
            [key] => 1
            [deckr] => 1
            [text] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => 3
            [title] => 3
            [date] => 30-07-2011
            [key] => 3
            [deckr] => 3
            [text] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => 2
            [title] => 2
            [date] => 30-06-2011
            [key] => 2
            [deckr] => 2
            [text] => 2
        )

)
```

это код

```
sort($arr);

foreach($arr as $key => $type) {
    echo"<h2>$key</h2>\n<ul>\n";
        foreach($type as $arr) {
            echo "<li>$arr</li>\n";
        }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

echo "</ul>\n";
```

а это что получилось на выходе:

```
0

    1
    1
    30-05-2011
    1
    1
    1

1

    2
    2
    30-06-2011
    2
    2
    2

2

    3
    3
    30-07-2011
    3
    3
    3
```

Comment: А теперь меняем $arr[1]['url'] на 0. Бац - и не работает...